# VS Code displaying non-English characters for an unsuported language

Tags: visual-studio-code

I get this error

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u021b' in position 25: character maps to

when I try to print characters in Romanian and I would like to know if there is any way to show these characters in the output.

I tried with the display language, but this language is not supported. I tried to change from utf-8 and didn't work.

I want to get rid of this error and be able to dispaly these characters, please.

Comment: does any of this help? https://www.google.com/search?q=%22UnicodeEncodeError%22+%22charmap%22+site:stackoverflow.com

Comment: No, they all just try changing the display characters circumventing my issue. It's what I tried before coming here and they solved the error, but not my issue.